# Senses without phenomenology: are they quales?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, time, phenomenology, qualia

Can there be sense experience without [phenomenological](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/) existence, in the Husserlian sense of the things themselves being given to consciousness?

Are they [like something](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia/)? Just as the smell of mint has its own qualitative aspect, is "like something"?

I am asking because, despite the apparent strangeness of it, I think that every time repeats its contents, including its sensuality. But the end (and beginning) of life is not phenomenologically apprehended.

Comment: Could you please illustrate your question with an example? What do you mean by "phenomenological" existence, what by "qualitative" existence? Thanks.

Comment: OK i tried. the former is difficult to exhaustively define and the latter difficult to communicate